# Python program that takes values of dice rolled by user and store these values in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python program that takes values of dice rolled by user and store these values in a dictionary.
If I enter some values, they are created but not updated. For example, if I write 1. it creates {'One':1} but if I write 1 again, it does not create {'One':2}.

```
dict1={}
count=0

while True:
    num=int(input('value :'))

    if num==-1:
        break
    elif num<-1 or num>6 or num==0:
        count+=1
        print('it should be valid')
    else:
        if num not in dict1:
            if num==1:
                dict1['One']=1
            if num==2:
                dict1['Two']=1
            if num==3:
                dict1['Three']=1
            if num==4:
                dict1['Four']=1
            if num==5:
                dict1['Five']=1
            if num==6:
                dict1['Six']=1
        else:
            dict1[num]+=1



print(dict1)
print(count)
```

Comment: If you fill the dict with string keys it won't contain an integer key.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for an integer key (`num`) against string keys (`['One', 'Two', ..]`).

If you can initialize the dictionary to be empty outside you could increment the count for each number instead of assigning 1 with `dict1['One']==1` conditionally on whether the key already exists.

Try this:

```
dict1={'One': 0, 'Two': 0, 'Three': 0, 'Four': 0, 'Five': 0, 'Six': 0}
count=0

while True:
    num=int(input('value :'))

    if num==-1:
        break
    elif num<-1 or num>6 or num==0:
        count+=1
        print('it should be valid')
    else:
        if num not in dict1:
            if num==1:
                dict1['One']+=1
            if num==2:
                dict1['Two']+=1
            if num==3:
                dict1['Three']+=1
            if num==4:
                dict1['Four']+=1
            if num==5:
                dict1['Five']+=1
            if num==6:
                dict1['Six']+=1

print(dict1)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code was that you never entered the condition where you increment with 1, `dict1[num]+=1`. Because the `key` in the dictionary was strings but you check `int`.

different approach if you don't want to initiate the dictionary from the beginning you could do the following:

```
dict1={}
count=0

def convertIntToStr(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 'one'
    elif x == 2:
        return 'two'
    elif x == 3:
        return 'three'
    elif x == 4:
        return 'four'
    elif x == 5:
        return 'five'
    elif x == 6:
        return 'six'


while True:
    num = int(input('value :'))
    if num==-1:
        break
    elif num<-1 or num>6 or num==0:
        count+=1
        print('it should be valid')
    else:
        num_str = convertIntToStr(num)
        if num_str not in dict1:
            dict1[num_str] = 1
        else:
            dict1[num_str] += 1



print(dict1)
print(count)
```

The input:

```
value :2
value :2
value :2
value :3
value :3
value :3
value :-1
```

The output:

```
{'two': 3, 'three': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is because the variable `num` is an integer, whereas your indices are strings ("One"). So in the check `if num not in dict1` and in the your last line in the while-loop, you try to use the integer as a key, even though the dictionary only contains strings as keys (e.g. "One", "Two").

So a quick fix would be the following:

```
dict1={}
count=0

while True:
    num=int(input('value :'))

    if num==-1:
        break
    elif num<-1 or num>6 or num==0:
        count+=1
        print('it should be valid')
    else:
        if num not in dict1:
            dict1[num]=1
        else:
            dict1[num]+=1
```

That is, if you do not mind using integers instead of strings. Otherwise, you can try and add a mapping for integers to strings, and use those:

```
dict1={}
count=0
int_to_string_map = {1: "One", 2: "Two", 3: "Three", 4: "Four", 5: "Five", 6: "Six"}

while True:
    num=int(input('value :'))

    if num==-1:
        break
    elif num<-1 or num>6 or num==0:
        count+=1
        print('it should be valid')
    else:
        string = int_to_string_map[num]
        if string not in dict1:
            dict1[string]=1
        else:
            dict1[string]+=1
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The probleme is that this condition `if num not in dict1:` will always be true as the keys of the dictionaries are strings but "num" is an integer. You should first convert this integers into their counterparts in str using for example the dictionary I suggested in my solution.

```
inttostr={1:'One',2:'Two',3:'Three',4:'Four',5:'Five',6:'Six'}
dict1={}
count=0

while True:
    num=int(input('value :'))

    if num==-1:
        break
    elif num<-1 or num>6 or num==0:
        count+=1
        print('it should be valid')
    else:
        if inttostr[num] not in dict1:
            dict1[inttostr[num]]=1            
        else:
            dict1[inttostr[num]]+=1



print(dict1)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check else block Condition. You are checking for dictionary Key instead of Value.

```
 else:
        if num not in dict1.values():
            if num==1:
```